# Dynamic Filterlist based on selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerquery, powerpivot

I try to implement the following within MS PowerPivot: I have a table with two necessary columns called `"ChartType"` and `"Size"`. Now what i want to implement is that whatever Charttype you're selecting, the Filterlist should adjust itself dynamically so that it only shows the Sizes from the "Size" column that are entangled with the selected ChartType.

So for example; when I have selected the ChartType `"Shipments"` and the available Sizes are `"1, 4, 6, 7"` only those Sizes should be shown within the Filterlist. Instead when I'm selecting `"Retails"` and the sizes entangled to that Charttype are `"2, 3, 5, 8"` only those values should be selectable within the Filterlist.

How can I implement such a dynamic filter list. I thought about writing a stored procedure, but I'm not sure if this would be an overkill when there are other ways in implementing it.

Thank you and BR

Comment: Which program are you using? PowerPivot is only available in Microsoft Excel. You also included `sql-server`, `tsql` and `powerbi`, is the source system a SQL Server database?

Comment: Hi, yes the source system is a SQL Server database. Is it not possible to let PowerPivot and SQL Server "communicate" during the using of the report?

Comment: PowerPivot imports the data, and does not like Power BI have a direct query option that lets you retrieve data while using the report. I think the solution is modifying your data model.